# Control de horarios con moment js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

En mi codigo de control de horarios, verifico si la hora actual esta dentro del rango de hora de apertura y hora de cierre este es mi codigo:

```
var ha = moment("00:00:00", 'H:mm:ss');
  var hc = moment("23:59:00", 'H:mm:ss');
  var hactual = moment("00:00:00", 'H:mm:ss');

  var h_apertura = ha.format('HH:mm:ss');
  var h_cierre = hc.format('HH:mm:ss');
  var h_actual = hactual.format('HH:mm:ss');

  if(h_apertura <= h_actual && h_actual <= h_cierre){
    alert("ABIERTO \nhora de apertura: "+h_apertura+"\nhora de cierre: "+h_cierre+"\nhora actual:"+h_actual);
    }else{
    alert("CERRADO \nhora de apertura: "+h_apertura+"\nhora de cierre: "+h_cierre+"\nhora actual:"+h_actual);
  }
```

en el codigo controlo que las 00:00 este dentro del rango de 00:00 y 23:59, mi duda es:

Es posible que una empresa abra su negocio a las 09:00 y cierre a las 02:00 de la madrugada? si es asi como haria ese control

De antemano agradezco sus respuestas 
adjunto mi [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dimoreno/cq1tboge/)

Comment: Como ser posible, lo es: cualquier discoteca o lugar de copas suele abrir hasta la madrugada.

Answer (score 5):

La librería moment.js está pensada para trabajar con fechas, no con simples horas, así que considero que no es la mejor solución. Es muy fácil hacer las comprobaciones manualmente:

```js
function formateaMomento(momento) {
  const regexp=/\d\d:\d\d(:\d\d)?/;
  if (regexp.test(momento)) {
    const units=momento.split(':');
    return ((+units[0]) * 3600) + (+units[1] * 60) + (+units[2] || 0);
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(formateaMomento('09:30'));

function generadorHorario(horaApertura,horaCierre) {
  let a=formateaMomento(horaApertura);
  let c=formateaMomento(horaCierre);
  
  console.log('horario: de',a,'a',c);
     
  return function (hora) {
    const h=formateaMomento(hora);
    
    //abierto a las 00:00
    if (a>c) {
      return (h >= a || h <= c);
    }
    
    return (h>=a && h<= c);
  }

}

let abiertoFn=generadorHorario('09:00','02:00');


console.log(abiertoFn('08:00'));
console.log(abiertoFn('23:00'));

let abiertoFn2=generadorHorario('09:00','23:00');
console.log(abiertoFn2('24:00'));
console.log(abiertoFn2('19:00'));
```

- La primera función pasa a un valor absoluto una hora dada (segundos pasados desde media noche).
- La segunda función genera un comprobador de horario: dada la hora de apertura y de cierre, crea una nueva función que comprueba que un momento dado está dentro del horario de apertura.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, soy nuevo en esto,  solo veo que tomas en cuenta la hora de apertura y la de cierre, donde se hace el control con la hora actual?

Comment: Cuando llamo a la función generada

Comment: entonces la respuesta false es cerrado y true abierto?

Comment: Exacto, así es como funciona el ejemplo